# Evaluate filter created using dsp.FIRFilter

Tags: matlab

In the code below I create a simple moving average (SMA) from known numerator coefficients. It's very cool that MatLab can do this as I have a number of sets of known coefficients that I want to look at using fvtool. The results in fvtool look completely reasonable.

I then wanted some input data to run through the filter, so I generate InData, plot it and run it through the filter using 'step'. This is where it gets weird:

1) The first time I run step the output data's amplitude is reduced. If I highlight the last 2 lines and hit F9 then the calculations are repeated and the amplitude grows. Interestingly, to get to full amplitude always take 'Length' F9 commands.

2) The phase of the data doesn't look correct in the plot. A simple moving average has Length delay to a step input, as shown in fvtool, but it's not delayed in OutData.

Maybe using step isn't the right way to do this? I'm very new to MatLab and it's the only way I discovered so far. How do I do this correctly in a single run?

NOTE: I'm completely open to any method that creates a system object filter block from known coefficients in the code itself.

Thanks!

```
%Create SMA filter
Length = 10;
N = repmat(1/Length, 1, Length);
SMA = dsp.FIRFilter('Numerator', N);
%View filter properties
fvtool(SMA);

%Create some data to run through filter
t=0:0.01:2;
InData = chirp(t,4,8,15);

%Plot input data
figure
plot(t, InData);
axis([0 2 -2 2]);
hold on;

%Run filter and add result to plot
OutData = step(SMA, InData);
plot(t, OutData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dsp.FIRFilter filters columns of input. Each column of input is considered a separate channel for filtering multi-channel inputs. In your case because you used a row vector, each sample is filtered as a separate channel. You essentially got first sample of filtered output for each input sample separately.

To filter the whole input you should make your input a column vector by transposing it.

```
InData = chirp(t,4,8,15).';
```

Comment: Bingo! So close and yet I was so, so far. ;-) Thanks much!